# Django ModelAdmin save_formset, how to get saved changes?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I can not cope with a simple task...
In the admin interface in the form of editing I have a linked object with a parent (TabularInline).

```
from django.contrib import admin
from core.models import Model, drop, install, Field, reinstall
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django import forms
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import get_app, get_models, get_model

class FieldAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Field

class FieldInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Field
    form = FieldAdminForm
    extra = 1

class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (FieldInline,)

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        if change:
            fake = get_model('goods', request.POST['name'])
            admin.site.unregister(fake)
            drop(fake)
        super(type(self), self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        new_model = Model.objects.get(name=request.POST['name'])
        new_fake = new_model.get_django_model()
        install(new_fake)
```

In save_related function, i was create model and install model to mysql table

```
def install(model):
    from django.core.management import sql, color

    style = color.no_style()

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, style)
    for statements in sql:
       cursor.execute(statements)

def drop(model):
    opts = model._meta
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+opts.db_table+"")
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

If i changed object in form, in save_related, i get a previously created model and delete a linked table but after saving field in the new table is not updated but remain old...

Field and Model models

```
class Model(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey(App, related_name='models')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    verbose_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    verbose_name_plural = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc =  models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "uploads/product/category/", blank=True)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.verbose_name_plural

    def __str__(self):
        return self.verbose_name_plural

    def get_django_model(self):

        fields = [(f.name, f.get_django_field()) for f in self.fields.all()]
        options = {'verbose_name':self.verbose_name, 'verbose_name_plural':self.verbose_name_plural}
        return create_model(str(self.name), fields, str(self.app.module), str(self.app.module), options)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('app', 'name'),)

def is_valid_field(field_data):
    if hasattr(models, field_data) and issubclass(getattr(models, field_data), models.Field):
        return
    raise ValidationError("This is not a valid field type.")

class Field(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, related_name='fields')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    verbose_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[is_valid_field])
    max_length = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    null = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="NULL")
    blank = models.BooleanField()

    def get_django_field(self):

        s = [(u'max_length', self.max_length), (u'verbose_name', self.verbose_name)]
        return getattr(models, self.type)(**dict(s))

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('model', 'name'),)
```